# Django model calculated field from one to many relationship

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have inherited some code with a django API and am trying to understand / get to grips with how to modify it appropriately..

I have a Model class called Asset and a Model class called Calibration.

A Calibration has a many to one relationship with Asset so:

```
class Calibration(Record):
    ...
    asset = models.ForeignKey(Asset, relatedName = "calibrationRecords")
    ...
```

And when I look at an individual Asset I can see the Calibration records as one would expect.

On another section of the API I can list all the Assets for a given Customer, however on this page, the calibrationRecords link is not shown.

This is kind of OK as I don't actually want to see all the Calibration records on this view, but I would like to see the last (most recent) Calibration record here, so in essence adding a calculated field onto this Model?

Where should this calculation go, and how is the best way to do it?

Comment: You need to give more details about the page where you want to show this. There's probably no need for this to be an a field, but it depends on your use case. You should probably show your serializer and view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a method to filter a model you can just add a model.Manager

E.g.

```
class ReviewerManager(models.Manager):
    def get_all_the_younger_reviewers(self):
        return self.get_queryset().filter(age__lt=18)

class Reviewer(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_lenght=50, null=False, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_lenght=50, null=False, blank=False)
    age = models.IntegerField()

    objects = ReviewerManager()

    @property
    def full_name(self):
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name
```

Now you can filter using new method:

Reviewer.objects.get_all_the_younger_reviewers()